# Combobox Datasource assignment throws Exception: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Tags: vb.net, exception, datatable, combobox

The following code results in an exception at the point that the datatable is assigned as the datasource for the combo box. The exception is " 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll" This code is situated in a procedure called from the form's load event. I have tried variations to the code including assignment as the datasource prior to filling the datatable, but results in the exactly the same exception. The debugger provides no additional contextual information regarding the exception. I have tried containing the following code within the same thread using a Synclock block to no avail. The combo box does successfully populate with data despite the exception thrown.

```
                Dim dtSuperFunds As DataTable = New DataTable()

                If dtSuperFunds.Columns.Count = 0 Then
                    dtSuperFunds.Columns.Add("SuperFundID", GetType(String))
                    dtSuperFunds.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
                    dtSuperFunds.Columns.Add("USI", GetType(String))
                End If
                If FillSuperFunds(dtSuperFunds) Then
                    'Me.SuperFunds.Items.Clear()
                    Me.SuperFunds.DataSource = dtSuperFunds 
                    Me.SuperFunds.ValueMember = "SuperFundID"
                    Me.SuperFunds.DisplayMember = "Name"
                End If
```

Comment: What's the point of checking whether a `DataTable` you just created has no columns? Of course it has no columns. You just created it. Maybe those lines of code are actually separate in your application and you only execute the first line once and the rest multiple times. That may not be ideal though, and maybe you should be creating a new `DataTable` every time.

Comment: *"The debugger provides no additional contextual information regarding the exception"*. It sure does. Did you look at the stack trace for the exception? When the *Exception Assistant* window is displayed, it should have a *View Details* link on it. Did you view those details?

Comment: The columns test was a remnant from my one of my many attempts to solve the problem when the datatable  was scoped at module level

Answer (score 0):

Thank you jmcilhinney. Your advice regarding the Exception Assistant window did indeed provide the context that I was looking for. The window indicated that the error resulted from assigning a datatable to a combo box with the sorted property set to 'true'

Comment: I guess my guess was off then. I was fairly confident as I've seen that so many times. You should always set the `DataSource` last though.